# Separate Django Auth Database...Different Table Name?

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I'm in the process of setting up a custom blog app using Django, with Mezzanine as the blog, which will be communicating with the auth system on my other Django app to handle all user authentication.

So far, I have set up an AuthRouter exactly like the example described here: [Multi DB Setup in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/)

However, my other Django app has a custom `AUTH_USER_MODEL` defined in its settings file.

As a result, when attempting to login to the blog, it is looking for a table with a different name from auth_user. I'm wondering if there is a way to specify the auth user table?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the code for your custom User model (or similar) in the blog project also. The you can set the proper table name with [db_table](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#db-table) (if auto generated is different). Then you will set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in your second project to point to your custom model defined in the same project. You also need to modify your router to work with this custom user model.

Comment: So I ended up creating my own app, and inside that app I created a User class for the model, and I pointed the db_table to the right spot. But now my issue is with the myuser_user_permissions.user_id - the column is actually named myuser_user_permissions.myuser_id.  Is there a way around that?

Comment: You need to name your model `User` instead of `MyUser` and `myuser_id` will become `user_id`. I don't know if the name of the table will cause you problems but if everything must match with the project 1 then in project 2 you need to create app with the same name and with the same models as in project 1 in order to use them.